# How to load only one image in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, image

So I have a website for a webcomic, which has many images. I created an interface which changes the source of the image every time the user clicks, "next", "previous", and so forth. (The comic files are indexed)

```
Pseudocode:

function goTo(word)  {
    num = (get current comic num);
    if (word = next):
        doc.getID("myComic").src = "comic"+(num+1)+".png";
        num++;
    // And similarly for prev, first, last, keywords...
}
```

This changes the image when I click the buttons, however, the webpage loads all the comic images at once, according to giftofspeed.com. This is bad, as I do not want my page to load many MBs of data at once; only the image that the src change calls on. How do I make sure that the page loads the one image that is viewed?

Comment: *... however, the webpage loads all the comic images at once* -- given code like you propose, that is definitely not true.

Comment: It's either that benchmarking website is broken, or you need to post *the real code you have* so we can see who's telling the truth.